# Help to avoid the battology with the collocation "to provide services"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I have a problem searching for proper synonyms of the words ***"service"*** and ***"to provide"***.

I've got the sentence with repeating words which sound ambiguous and complicated. I tried to find some words to replace those but it changes the meaning completely.

Here is the sentence

> Support provides service of informative emails delivery about
>   services provided and supported by our department.

I thought I could replace provide with ***to pursue*** or just ***to do***, but I am not sure with it. Maybe you may help me dealing with this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think ***battology*** and all derivatives are ridiculously rare words, that would be completely opaque to the vast majority of English native speakers (including *me*, and I actually have a degree in English Literature! :) so they're best avoided completely.

Comment: Note that most people would probably just say ***We provide support by email [only]*** and leave it at that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, I had to look up "battology" even though I'm familiar with obscure words like "pleonasm" that might be applied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say **our** you can say **we**.

> We send out informative emails about the services we provide.

or

> We in Support send out informative emails about the services we provide.

or

> We in Support send out informative emails about the services our department provides.

You can change **department** to **team** if Support is not a full-fledged department in its own right.

The main stroke of verbosity in your original is the phrase **provides service of informative emails delivery**

Comment: But there is the need to point that it is *Support* who doing it.

Comment: Presumably that fact is already established in the context of your text, so that the recipient would understand who **We** refers to.  But you can say "We in Support send out..."

Comment: It is not. And *Support* is not the word that I was concerned about.

Comment: Is "informative" needed? Do you send non-informative emails?

Comment: @djna: I don't see anything wrong with "informative".  It distinguishes these emails from haranguing emails telling people to stop cold-booting their PCs when they run into trouble, or reminder emails to shutdown their PCs at night, and so forth.

Comment: @djna  Tᴚoɯɐuo is right, it is to describe the nature of the emails. That is not personal emails or promo emails. They are exactly informative.

Comment: May be a matter of taste, but for me "informational email" jars. Focus on describing the content rather than the email, subtle distinction. As per my answer: I am sending you information via email, rather than an informational email. You're expressing your desire to help the user. I'm over-sensitive but I get irritated by IT speak. Mis-type my password my bank puts up a huge THIS IS AN IMPORTANT MESSAGE (tiny text) your password is wrong. The emphasis is in the wrong place. Informational emails. Even the haranguing ones are informative. You've sent an email about your services. Enough.

Comment: Maybe it will sound better if I change it to the phrase *"Support provides informative mailout service regarding our department provided and  supported services"*?

Comment: @Gamilato: Sorry, you're going in the wrong direction. That's terrible.  Write as you would speak, and then clean it up a bit.  **informative mailout service** is not something any native speaker would say, and a native speaker would not make an adjective "department-provided" but would use a subordinate clause, "which our department provides".

Comment: Okay, but is the phrase *informative mailout* okay? Is it okay to use it?

Comment: No, it is not ok.   "informative mailouts" is unnatural. "mailouts" is colloquial.  *We do mailouts from time to time to keep you informed of the services we provide.*

Comment: Maybe it is better to leave it as it is, with those repeating words? And it will be *IT Support provides informative email delivery regarding services provided or supported by IT Department.*

Comment: "informative email delivery" is crap. You do not "provide...delivery". What is wrong with the verb "send out"?

Comment: So it would sound appropriate for formal document language if I'll write *IT Support sends out informative emails regarding services provided or supported by ITD*?

Comment: There's nothing informal about that. Neutral language is fine. But that sentence is vague. What you're saying there is no more than "We send out emails. These emails are about the services we provide or support."   "regarding" is just a synonym for "about". Are you announcing these services?  Describing these services? Also, I'm not really sure what the phrase "services we support" would mean. What does it mean to support a service?

Comment: It is to introduce this so called service of info mail-out to colleagues. By *support a service* meant that there is the service that is provided by department, so when something is wrong with it, the department does support function to that service (e.g. repairing and restoring works).

Comment: I still don't understand what it would mean to "support a service".  What are "works" or what is "restoring works"?

Comment: I meant the works that the specialists do to restore the service or to repair it.

Comment: So you're actually servicing a service.

Comment: Yes, if really roughly speaking. But I just want to clarify for the reader-user what it is meant under just *service*, what actual role the department plays in that service providing.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the word "service" or its synonyms to describe the sending of emails about services provided.

The Support Department keep our Customers (Clients, Colleagues?) informed about the services and assistance we provide via regular emails and also the Support Website (link).